# iPhone -- saving to kml file on mapkit

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps, mapkit, kml

I have many coordinates to save in KML format on the iPhone.

Is the best way to just use the XML libraries and save it using the KML markers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a look at one of the KML parsing libraries for Objective-C:

Specifically you might want to try: https://github.com/mapbox/Simple-KML